# Scrollbar is not showing in my first Website file

Tags: html, css, web, scrollbar

i already looked into many different questions but could not find a solution to why my scrollbar is not showing.
I hope somebody can tell me why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  
  
    .btn {
  background-color: rgb(126, 128, 129); /* Blue background */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* White text */
  padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
  font-size: 15px; /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer; }/* Mouse pointer on hover */
    .btn:hover {background-color: rgb(172, 172, 172);}
    .btn {float: right}
    img.resize {
        float: left;
  width:285px;
  height:75px;
} 
.topnav {
   
  background-color: rgb(185, 29, 29);
  overflow: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  top: 0px;
  position:fixed;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav2 {
  margin-top:30px; 
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  overflow:auto;}
.topnav2 a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;}
    .topnav2 a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
.dropbtn {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   border: none;
   color:rgb(126, 128, 129);
   font-size: 14px;

}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.sticky {
    margin-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky2 {
    margin-top: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#search {margin-right: 1px;}

#scrollbar {overflow-y: scroll;
height:100ex;}
</style>

<html>    
<body  id="scrollbar">
  
<title>ILIAS DHfPG</title>
<div class="topnav ; sticky2">
<button class="btn">Anmelden</button>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button id="search" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
<div class=sticky>
<div><img class="resize" src='https://ilias.dhfpg.de/Customizing/global/skin/dhfpgde/images/HeaderIcon.svg'></div>
<div class=topnav2>
    
<div class=dropdown>
    <button style="font-family:arial"  class=dropbtn>ILIAS-Überblick</button>
    <i style="color: grey" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
<div style="font-size: 14px;font-family:arial"  class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">öffentlich</a>
        <p style="font-size:13px;background-color:rgb(185, 29, 29);color:rgb(255, 255, 255)">Weiterbildungsmöglichkeiten</p>
        <a href="#">Annerkennung Trainerlizenzen</a>
        <a href="#">Weiterbildungs bei der BSA-Akademie</a>
        <a href="#">Weiterbildung an der DHfPG</a> 
</div>
</div>
<div class=dropdown>
    <button style="font-family:arial" class=dropbtn>Service</button> 
    <i style="color: grey;" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
<div style="font-size: 14px;font-family:arial"  class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">FAQ-ILIAS-Nutzung</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class=dropdown>
    <button  style="font-family:arial" class=dropbtn>Zuletzt besucht</button>
    <i style="color: grey" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <div style="font-size: 14px;font-family:arial"  class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Zuletzt besuche Seite</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

That's the piece of code.
If there is more code needed let me know.
I added some code now.
I als have a long paragraph under it so the website
is filled and has something to scroll.

Comment: It is showing but not working you can not scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your height is full and no need to scroll (when you can see everything), Scroll appears when height limited and not showing all of them to help you see items.

**EDIT:** You used `position: fixed;` An element with `position: fixed;` is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.

```html
<body id="scrollbar">
    
<style>
  
  
    .btn {
  background-color: rgb(126, 128, 129); /* Blue background */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* White text */
  padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
  font-size: 15px; /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer; }/* Mouse pointer on hover */
    .btn:hover {background-color: rgb(172, 172, 172);}
    .btn {float: right}
    img.resize {
        float: left;
  width:285px;
  height:75px;
} 
.topnav {
   
  background-color: rgb(185, 29, 29);
  overflow: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  top: 0px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav2 {
  margin-top:30px; 
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  overflow:auto;}
.topnav2 a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;}
    .topnav2 a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
.dropbtn {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   border: none;
   color:rgb(126, 128, 129);
   font-size: 14px;

}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.sticky {
    margin-top: 50px;
  
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky2 {
    margin-top: 15px;
 
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#search {margin-right: 1px;}

#scrollbar {overflow-y: scroll;
height:100ex;}
</style>

    

  
<title>ILIAS DHfPG</title>
<div class="topnav ; sticky2">
<button class="btn">Anmelden</button>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button id="search" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="sticky">
<div><img class="resize" src="https://ilias.dhfpg.de/Customizing/global/skin/dhfpgde/images/HeaderIcon.svg"></div>
<div class="topnav2">
    
<div class="dropdown">
    <button style="font-family:arial" class="dropbtn">ILIAS-Überblick</button>
    <i style="color: grey" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
<div style="font-size: 14px;font-family:arial" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">öffentlich</a>
        <p style="font-size:13px;background-color:rgb(185, 29, 29);color:rgb(255, 255, 255)">Weiterbildungsmöglichkeiten</p>
        <a href="#">Annerkennung Trainerlizenzen</a>
        <a href="#">Weiterbildungs bei der BSA-Akademie</a>
        <a href="#">Weiterbildung an der DHfPG</a> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button style="font-family:arial" class="dropbtn">Service</button> 
    <i style="color: grey;" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
<div style="font-size: 14px;font-family:arial" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">FAQ-ILIAS-Nutzung</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button style="font-family:arial" class="dropbtn">Zuletzt besucht</button>
    <i style="color: grey" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <div style="font-size: 14px;font-family:arial" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Zuletzt besuche Seite</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

</div><div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div></body>
```

Comment: @Noobie You should put at least one item.
When its empty no need to scroll then it won't apply.

Comment: Yea i put a random paragraph text that overflows the border.

Comment: @Noobie
So it worked?
If you want accept my answer...

Comment: No it did not work. maybe because i have 2 Navbars in the code also.

Comment: @Noobie
Can you share more code's?
Then i can face the problem my self.

Comment: @Noobie https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp you can see the property of position: fixed;

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollbar is working but it doesn't seem to work because your div position is fixed. Change it to static(default) or you can remove that filed and whenever your page size increased than your device height it will add a scroll bar automatically on the page for overflowing content.

Try this:

```
#scrollbar {overflow-y: scroll;
height:200ex;}

.sticky2 {
    margin-top: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
    margin-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```